# How use two types of UICollectionViewCell for a single UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm looking to add another custom `UICollectionVIewCell` to my `UICollectionView`. So I would now have two custom cells in the same collectionView. All of the `delegate` methods I have put in are for the first `collectionViewCell` (collectionVIewCellA).

I've added collectionViewCellB to my storyboard, but am unsure of how to tell the `viewController` about this new custom cell and to configure it. Has anyone done this?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by,

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     if (condition for cellA) {
          //dequeue cell with cell A identifier
          //configure cell
     } else {
          //dequeue cell with cell B identifier
          //configure cell
     }
}
```

assuming the collectionview cell A and B have different reuse identifiers configured in storyboard.

You can use the same logic in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` delegate method to update height depends on cell

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: thanks akhilraj how to set height for two type of cells

Comment: you can use the same logic used in `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` like `if (condition for cellA){} else {}` in `- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` delegate method

Answer (score 0):

you set condition in collectionView `cellForItemAtIndexPath` Delegate method like this way.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // your cell condition here
    if (self.isMainMenu) {
        MainCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MainCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   if(cell!=nil){// cell nil condition
   }
// cell coding here

return cell;
    }
    else{
    // second custom cell code here
        ItemCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ItemCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        // cell coding here
        return cell;
    }
}
```

increase cell height

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(first cell condition)
    {        
        return CGSizeMake((collectionView.frame.size.width/4)-5, (collectionView.frame.size.width/4)-5);// your required height
    }
    else{
         return CGSizeMake((collectionView.frame.size.width/4)-5, (collectionView.frame.size.width/4)-5);// your required height
    }

}
```

Comment: how to find the two type of cell in one collectionview if nil or not

Comment: `if(cell!=nil){}` check condition in first cell condition @EvelinPrissy

Comment: how to add cell when array count ends

Comment: check condition `if([yourarr lastObject]==indexPath.row){}` if match then create cell other wise not.@EvelinPrissy